# iTextSharp saving a filled form (C#.Net)

Tags: c#, itext

On an asp.net page I am allowing my user to enter data to my pdf form, all I want to do is once they submit, save that form as a PDF file under different name into a directory.

Do I have to read all fields (request.form) one-by-one and use pdfstamper to save into a new file or is there a quick way to do a clone of the page and save under different name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set them all at once:

StackOverflow doesn't like '(' or ')' in its links

1. Make sure your PDF is submitting FDF data
2. [`acroFields.setFields()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#setFields(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FdfReader))